# Not getting all the data of a order like shipping cost and more while using eBay getOrder api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, ebay-api

Trying to get all data for order using getOrder api call but not getting shiiping cost and some more data please help if anyone have solution...

Answer (score 1):

See the link, you can get the attributes and use in your code

[eBay::API::XML::DataType::ShippingDetailsType](http://search.cpan.org/dist/eBay-API/lib/eBay/API/XML/DataType/ShippingDetailsType.pm)

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of element  in the XML as RETURNALL, This would return all the data of a  particular order and also the shipping details.

Sample Xml will be --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
<CreateTimeFrom>2015-12-01T20:34:44.000Z</CreateTimeFrom>
<CreateTimeTo>2015-12-10T20:34:44.000Z</CreateTimeTo>
<OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
<OrderStatus>Active</OrderStatus>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```